# Running main in prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I got following code (from [this](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse54) tutorial)

```
main:- 
         open(’houses.txt’,read,Str), 
         read_houses(Str,Houses), 
         close(Str), 
         write(Houses),  nl. 

   read_houses(Stream,[]):- 
         at_end_of_stream(Stream). 

   read_houses(Stream,[X|L]):- 
         \+  at_end_of_stream(Stream), 
         read(Stream,X), 
         read_houses(Stream,L).
```

*houses.txt:*

```
   gryffindor. 
   hufflepuff. 
   ravenclaw. 
   slytherin.
```

I load it like this:

```
$ swipl -s flp18-log.pl
```

The problem comes when I want to start main "function" ->

```
?- main.
ERROR: Undefined procedure: main/1
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         main/0
ERROR: 
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] main([])
ERROR:    [8] prolog_main:main at /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/HEAD-e6bbda4/libexec/lib/swipl-7.7.12/library/main.pl:82
ERROR:    [7] <user>
   Exception: (9) main([]) ?
```

I spent hours figuring out what's wrong. Unsuccessfully. Can you help?

Comment: Only one detail, is: open(’houses.txt’,read,Str), , with **'**, not with **’**.

Comment: @MLStud That's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is:

`open('houses.txt',read,Str)`

with ', not with ’.